Ethnic background of characters in Rulfo's short stories
In George D. Schade's introduction to his translation of Juan Rulfo's The Burning Plain and Other Stories, he surveys and summarises this collection of short stories, with specific references to each of them over the course of his introduction. A couple of times, he uses the word "Indian" to describe the characters:

Rulfo's world is extremely primitive and profoundly alien to us, at least in its outer aspect, though it is plagued within by the same convulsive agony and fears that strike men’s hearts everywhere. The atmosphere is full of repressions and is often mute — a paralytic world seemingly beyond the orbits of time and space. Crude and perverse passions, solitude and death stand out as tangible phenomena against the opaqueness of the Indian characters’ tragic lives.


The elements of the harsh physical environment combine with the Mexican Indian’s fatalism to forge almost a symbiosis of man and landscape. The parched, dry plain is overwhelming. The Indian accepts life as it is there, and his acts are almost inevitable. He is perpetually in flight, or wracked by fear, mistrust, and remorse, often losing his few cherished possessions and his peace of mind. Impotence and despair reign, and death rattles in the scorching air, the howling wind, the throttling dust of the plain.

(two separate paragraphs, not together; emphasis added by me)
Did I miss something? Are the characters (some? most? all?) meant to be Native Americans? (I know nothing about the demographics of Mexico, but some quick scrolling through Wikipedia tells me that around 10-20% of Mexicans today are considered indigenous, and most of them seem to live in the south of Mexico; I don't know if their numbers or distribution were different in Rulfo's time, and the history of who is considered indigenous or not has apparently been complicated.) What, if anything, within the stories indicates the ethnic background of the characters? (To readers more clued-up than me on race issues in Mexico, that is. It never crossed my mind when I was reading the stories.) Or does Schade mean something else by "Indian"?

In a blog on Mexican lit. in the 20th c.: https://luislopezdemesa.edu.co/index2.php?id=48152&idmenutipo=4942 His characters are peasants (campesinos), simple people who speak like the common Mexican  with their Mexicanisms, offensive speech and features proper to a colloquial registe. But their feelings are the same as the rest of the men from those times, who live with the anxiety of having seen everything they believed to be true destroyed.  Some campesinos were metizos

The Mexican race issue is very fraught. That said, there is a lot of mixture of indigenous and Spanish-descended whites. The lower one is on the economic ladder, the less white one would be. No, the characters are not meant to be native Americans per se. What is important is their influence on the peasantry into which they were incorporated as it were.

FWIW Rulfo claimed to have never included an indigenous character in his works.

@ClaraDíazSanchez Interesting! That would make a good answer, even by itself (with a source of course).

@ClaraDíazSanchez Yes, but most Mexican peasants are of mixed heritage.

It is worth noting that the only occurrence of the word "Indian" is in Schade's Introduction - it is not used at all in the stories of The Burning Plain (El llano en llamas). This fits with Rulfo's own statements on the use of indigenous characters, which is that he never used such characters in his own works. In a conference given in his honor at the Universidad Central de Venezuela in 1974, a student asked him whether he thought that his works explored the Indian viewpoint, and Rulfo replied1 (translation mine):

The Mexican Indian, like all Indians, has a very difficult mentality:
it is very difficult to enter into his mentality. No, I don't have any
indigenous characters nor have I ever written about Indians.
I know them well... I have worked with them for more than fifteen
years, but their mentality is very difficult to penetrate. [...]
Naturally one does not understand them, and it is very difficult, as I
said, to write with indigenous characters since one does not know what
they think, how they think or why they act in a certain way. And that,
perhaps, answers this question. But no, there are no Indians in my
literature.

(bolding mine).
While one cannot always take an author at their word (what they write, and what they think they write can be very different things), I don't see any reason to disbelieve Rulfo here. He consciously chose not to represent Indians because he thought he could not present them authentically. Indeed in an essay “Notas sobre la literatura indígena en México” Rulfo referred to indigenous literature as being "impossible", because so little was known about these cultures.
Why then should Schade use the word "Indian" in the Introduction? I think that this comes to a simple misidentification. Elisa Rizo2 wrote that

Rulfo incorporates characters belonging to the subaltern classes that
show the discrepancies between the official discourse that emerged
from the Revolution and the reality of the failure of the armed
movement in matters of agriculture and economic development. However,
[this] does not imply that his literature can or should be considered
to be about indigenous themes.

Subalterns ("of inferior rank") are populations excluded from the hierachy of power. While native Indian populations do frequently fall into this class, so do the typical Mexican peasants that Rulfo writes about.  We see this clearly in They Gave us the Land, for example, where a group of campesinos (peasants) are swindled and manipulated by the Mexican elites. So because Rulfo writes about powerless populations of this kind, there is a lazy assumption that they must therefore be Indian.


Quoted, for example, in "Juan Rulfo y la representacion literaria del
mestizaje", Eliza G. Rizo (2003).

Quoted in "La Otredad Indígena en el Panorama Sociocultural Mexicano del Siglo XX", Martiza Maldonaldo, PhD thesis (University of Arizona) (2017).



This difference may also be a reflection of the different characterization of racial minorities in the U.S. and in Mexico. In the U.S. in the 19th century, if you had 1/8 African-American ancestry, you were considered black, and I suspect this was still true (at least informally) in the 1960s and 1970s. In Mexico, I suspect the majority of citizens have more than 1/8 Indian ancestry, but they are not considered to be Indians.

Thanks for the info! Now I feel less happy about having read Schade's translation - if he could make such a mistake in his interpretation of Rulfo's work, maybe he also made other misunderstandings in translation.

@Randal'Thor Learn Spanish! -  it's the only way to get the full picture (and it seems to have worked for Tsundoku)

We say lower classes, typically. There is no strict line between Spanish-descended Mexicans and native people in the peasant strata in Mexico. The peasantry is a mixture of the two. La mezcla principal en la Nueva España fue la de españoles e indígenas. https://www.mexicodesconocido.com.mx/mestizaje.html The main mixture in New Spain was the Spanish and the indigenous people.

@ClaraDíazSanchez Tsundoku is a pro in languages, far more than I'll ever be :-)
